# Bijection between complement of $W$ and $Hom(V/W,W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

I'm trying to prove

> Let $W \subset V$ be vector spaces over some field. Call a subspace $W′$ to be a complement of $W$ if $V = W \oplus  W ′$. Prove that the set of all complements of $W$ in $V$ is in bijection with the vector space $Hom(V/W,W)$ of all linear transformations from $V/W$ to$ W$.

Consider the short exact sequence $$ 0 \longrightarrow W \longrightarrow V \longrightarrow V/W \longrightarrow 0$$  I managed to prove that $ Hom(V/W,W) \hookrightarrow Hom(V,W)$. From here how do you show the bijection between them? (Note: $V $ may not be finite dimensional vector space).

Thanks.
Akshay.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: First put the complementes in bijection to projections $V \to W$ with Image $W$. These won't form a vector space but a affine space. Then try to find a bijection between this space and $Hom(V/W, W)$.

Answer (score 0):

Another direction to that of @verduss : a subspace of V is a complement of W iff it intersects every coset of W at exactly one point

Comment: I tried to do that... but stuck.Please help me further.

Comment: You need to pick one complement to be sent to the zero homomorphism. This choice is arbitrary